# RSA keys in Perl

Tags: perl, encryption, cryptography, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

I have simple RSA encoding/decoding script, such as:

```
use Crypt::RSA;

my $rsa = new Crypt::RSA;
my($public, $private) = $rsa->keygen( Size => 2048 )
                        or die $rsa->errstr();

my $email = '...';

my $em = $rsa->encrypt( Message => $email, Key => $public  );
my $dm = $rsa->decrypt( Ciphertext => $em, Key => $private );

print "$dm\n";
```

However I want to modify this script to use RSA keys as **e**, **d** and **n** values, such as:

```
e => 10001
d => 135b03530e94874283f0f0000ffff0001
n => 24000c6c9620886831124848640044901
```

How can I **convert** these three parameters into `Crypt::RSA::Key` objects and vice versa?

Or, how can I use these three parameters with `Crypt::RSA` for encryption and decryption?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I advice you check this module: [Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA](http://search.cpan.org/~perler/Crypt-OpenSSL-RSA-0.28/RSA.pm), [Crypt::OpenSSL::Bignum](http://search.cpan.org/~iroberts/Crypt-OpenSSL-Bignum-0.04/Bignum.pm), or check how I use it one of my repository in github: [Perl backend for Jcryption](https://github.com/fxzuz/Perl-backend-for-Jcryption)

**Create RSA by parameters n,e,d**

```
use strict;

use Crypt::OpenSSL::Bignum;
use Crypt::OpenSSL::Random;
use Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA;

my $param_ref = {
    n => 'C8F19E3A7C18A5FE6D1DE07926F4E6403EA6558EE4892D29155F2C52678E210FE5D61DBC9EC77F2DD39FC8D9F2717F23629B7E18BDB38AADF9FC5BF1CA968C67F4BF0F2D6657E1374A845048B6CDCB2B8B2B3F31BF7F134A11B9A063EB7C326B27C0027955637E6089293F5F4CD40F5B91142BBA61B8E473A8D14B447896B5FD',
    e => '010001',
    d => '574C612997703DED630A6FD3329182D6B6611D1A8F3EE957C7E9292043CD03A01C82013948E1F2E6BDE1D5289AA3A450832E7A81D528833F4233D8DE1ADD7CF1878CBACDE64DE4364F8B73093753D6E322732EAEC942281CE4AF55D212E77EC4A108708864D3F86A67C63FBE8206A543A42ABF45E56C1E41A2F2BA0CCC1C8001',
};

my $n = Crypt::OpenSSL::Bignum->new_from_hex($param_ref->{n});
my $e = Crypt::OpenSSL::Bignum->new_from_hex($param_ref->{e});
my $d = Crypt::OpenSSL::Bignum->new_from_hex($param_ref->{d});

my $rsa = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_key_from_parameters($n, $e, $d);

printf "private key is: %s\n", $rsa->get_private_key_string();
printf "public key (in PKCS1 format) is: %s\n", $rsa->get_public_key_string();
```

**Get key parameters from RSA object**

```
use strict;

use Crypt::OpenSSL::Bignum;
use Crypt::OpenSSL::Random;
use Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA;

my $rsa = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->generate_key(2048);
my ($n, $e, $d, $p, $q) = $rsa->get_key_parameters();

printf "private key is: %s\n", $rsa->get_private_key_string();
printf "public key (in PKCS1 format) is: %s\n", $rsa->get_public_key_string();
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to use `Crypt::OpneSSL::RSA` to encrypt/decrypt the message with **n+e** and **d+e** values? I need to allow public to decrypt message and encryption makes private, so I cannot distribute private key from `$rsa->get_private_key_string`. Please advice.

Comment: Yes for encrypt message by public key it's enough (n+e), for decrypt by private key it's enough (n+e+d) p+q - help with fast computation.

Comment: Read my comment again - reverse: I need to use public key for decryption and private key for encryption... Possible?

Comment: @Ωmega, yes you can use private key for encryption using the aptly named `private_encrypt` method of `Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA`